# Digging technique counter

Tags: unity-game-engine, while-loop, unityscript

I'm making and game which has digging as it's feature so I need timer which will count exact float (in seconds) and then destroy gameObject. This is what I tried now but it's freezing unity:

```
function Update()
{

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
                        digTime = 1.5; // in secounds
                  }
                  while (!Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) // why is this infinite loop?
                  {               
                  digtime -= Time.deltaTime;
                  if (digtime <= 0)
                  {
                  Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                  }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic example how you can check if player has clicked for a certain time period.

```
#pragma strict

// This can be set in the editor
var DiggingTime = 1.5;

// Time when last digging started
private var diggingStarted = 0.0f;

function Update () {
    // On every update were the button is not pressed reset the timer
    if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        diggingStarted = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    }

    // Check if the DiggingTime has passed from last setting of the timer
    if (diggingStarted + DiggingTime < Time.timeSinceLevelLoad)
    {
        // Do the digging things here
        Debug.Log("Digging time passed");

        // Reset the timer
        diggingStarted = Time.timeSinceLevelLoad;
    }
}
```

It is firing every `DiggingTime` of seconds even the player is holding the button down. If you want that the player needs to release the button and press again one solution is to add Boolean telling if the timer is on or not. It can be set true on `GetMouseButtonDown` and false on `GetMouseButtonUp`.

Answer (score 0):

Update function is called every frame. If you add a while loop inside this function waiting for the mouseButtonUp, you'll freeze Unity for sure.

You don't need the while loop. Just check GetMouseButtonUp without while loop.

EDIT

This is the Update function:

```
void Update ()
{
    if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown( 0 ) )
    {
        digTime = 1.5f;
    }
    else if ( Input.GetMouseButton( 0 ) )
    {
        if ( digTime <= 0 )
        {
            Destroy( hit.collider.gameObject );
        }
        else
        {
            digTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Minor controls should be added to avoid destroying gameObject several times, but this is the idea to proceed

Comment: Okay, but that is not what  I want. I want to allow players to dig while they are holding left click down. If I checked if MouseButtonUp is true, I'm forcing player to release the click so he can actually dig out what he wants?! How do I achieve something like this: while holding left click start timer, if timer is over and click is not released yet, destroy the object?

Comment: I have just edited my answer with an example of posible solution